# Delphi Xe2 Package x64

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe2

Let's admit, I create new package in Delphi Xe2. I keep under a name "My". I add a simple component "MyComponent". I compile, I receive file Bpl in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\My.bpl.

I add a platform "Win x64". 
I compile, I receive C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\Win64\My.bpl.

...\Bpl\Win64\My.bpl to establish as new package does not give, writes "is not windows x32 applications".
The first is established normally and on a palette the component appears "MyComponent".
If to bring to are mute the index of a mouse will appear hint where it will be written, that it x32-compatible.
And at native component Delphi - at all x32-64 compatible.
Together with a disk to Xe2 there is a free disk with Free and Tral components if to put therefrom for example OverByteIcs or Ip*Works, that at them at all components will be 32-64х compatibility.

Questions:
1. How to establish the x64 the version package?
2. How to achieve, that the component had a compatibility 32-64, and not just 32?

P.S. Bad English language: ON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi IDE is 32 bit and so can only load 32 bit designtime packages. You can of course create 64 bit runtime packages.

Comment: Exactly as you have done. Add platform x64, select x64 platform, compile. You just can't install the x64 target into the IDE at design time.

Comment: It seems clearly. I.e. I can collect, I can use this BPL at project compilation, but establish in IDE I can not?

Comment: That is correct. If you have components that stream to the .dfm you will have to build a 32 bit target and install that, even if at runtime you load the 64 bit target.

Answer (score 3):

Has earned, has understood!

1. We create empty package
2. We add the component, for example Button and it is specified what platforms for a component (**the key moment are necessary!**)

*Example*

```
unit GuButton;

interface

uses
  System. SysUtils, System. Classes, Vcl. Controls, Vcl. StdCtrls;

type
  [ComponentPlatformsAttribute (pidWin32 or pidWin64)] // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  TButtonGu = class (TButton)
  private
    {Private declarations}
  protected
    {Protected declarations}
  public
    {Public declarations}
  published
    {Published declarations}
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents (' Gu ', [TButtonGu]);
end;
```

We keep, we compile under x32. We add a platform x64 (in options should be registered, that directories under platforms different).
We compile under x64. We receive 2 BPL (as in the first question). We establish x32. We look - new component ButtonGu - 32-64 compatible was added.

Here I that wanted, all thanks.
In addition http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/64-bit_Cross-Platform_Application_Development_for_Windows